# Delphi access violation error on specific line of code

Tags: delphi, treeview

I have a `TTreeView` that gets populated from a `DB table`.
I then run this code & `query` to get a `value` from another `column` in that table, based on the `TTreeView` item checked and add it to a `TMemo`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i: Integer;
test: string;

begin
  for i:=0 to TreeView1.Items.Count do
   begin
     if TreeView1.Items[i].Checked then
      begin
       test := TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Text;
        try
         Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT column2 FROM someTable WHERE column1='''+test+'''';
         Query1.Open;
        finally
         Memo1.Lines.Add(Query1.FieldByName('column2').Value);
        end;
       Query1.Close;
      end;
   end;
for i:=0 to TreeView1.Items.Count do TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Checked := false;
end;
```

Everything works fine with the exception of an `Access Violation error` I get once I fire this up.

Delphi debugger identifies it as originating on this line of code:

```
if TreeView1.Items[i].Checked then
```

and says: `Expression illegal in evaluator`

I'm not understanding what the problem with that line of code is.
Care to share your thoughts?

Comment: `count`is 1-based, whereas `items` is indexed from zero. So you get an AV when `i` reaches `count` which is 1 more than can be indexed. You need to change this line to read `for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do`

Comment: @nolaspeaker Oh, I see! Made the change and it indeed works properly with no AV. Thanks for the help. Care to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry to say so, but this q doesn't seem to merit upvotes..  The problem is an elementary mistake (assuming an array is 1-based) and there are countless examples on SO.

Comment: @MartynA Feel free to downvote it then if it's that important to you. I simply missed it entirely, being focused on the Delphi debugger that indicated a different line to be the problem. I'll just be glad I got the help and added another mental emphasis to triple check code and not follow the debugger blindly in the future. Sorry to say but I'm of the opinion that upvotes or downvotes shouldn't be that important as opposed to helping someone. I wish you a good evening :)

Comment: @t1f, since you are familiar with debugging, take another step in your skill toolbox and set the range/overflow flags in the debugger.

Comment: @LURD Thanks for mentioning. Just googled that and came across 2 useful reads on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical rookie mistake (which I sometimes still make myself)

***count*** is 1-based, whereas ***items*** is indexed from zero. So you get an AV when ***i*** reaches ***count*** which is 1 more than can be indexed. You need to change this line

```
for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count do
```

to

```
for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
```

There's 2 places in your code where that change needs to be applied.

Comment: Appreciate the help.

Comment: "There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors."

Comment: I guess that makes 4 problems...